# React router doesn't show '/' as home when i add homepage property to package json for github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

When I deployed my react app to github pages, i only get myusername.github.io/ as the home component instead of myusername.github.io/project as the home component, which is the link github gives me. After some digging I found that the culprit is react router. I tried `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` but it's not working. My App component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <ScrollToTop>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Header />
      <BurgerMenu />
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'} component={Home} />
      <Route path='/plants-accessories' component={LivePlants} />
      <Route exact path='/checkout' component={Checkout} />
      </Switch> 
    </ScrollToTop>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

index:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor} >
    <App />
    </PersistGate>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: What exactly is happening, and what did you expect instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `basename` prop on the `BrowserRouter` route component. You also don't need to repeat the base URL in the `Route` components. You should be able to get rid of `Router` component as you're already using `BrowserRouter`.

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor} >
    <App />
    </PersistGate>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

app.js

```
function App() {
  return (
      <ScrollToTop>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Header />
      <BurgerMenu />
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/plants-accessories' component={LivePlants} />
      <Route exact path='/checkout' component={Checkout} />
      </Switch> 
    </ScrollToTop>
  )
}

export default App;
```